# In R, how do you turn a vector into a 1xn data frame?

Tags: r

I get city data (locInfo) from an API and it would sometimes give me a data frame (in the case where there are more than one cities) and sometimes give a vector (in the case where only one city match the search criteria). I would like to select the fourth column of locInfo using`locInfo[,4]` but unfortunately when there is only one city this would give me an error. How do I tell R to interpret `locInfo[,4]` as returning the fourth column/element without first checking if it is a vector, and if it is then convert locInfo to a 1xn matrix using `matrix()` or `data.frame()`?

Comment: `locInfo[,4,drop=FALSE]`

Comment: can you give us a (small) [reproducible example](http://tinyurl.com/reproducible-000) please?

Answer (score 0):

```
aaa <- letters[1:10]
data.frame(matrix(aaa, nrow = 1))
    #   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6 X7 X8 X9 X10
    # 1  a  b  c  d  e  f  g  h  i   j
```